# Anova with unequal variances via regression modeling

Tags: regression, anova, generalized-linear-model, heteroscedasticity

I would like to fit a one-way between-subject anova that *assumes unequal variances* between groups.

Reproducible example:

```r
library(emmeans)
library(car)

set.seed(123)
n <- 50
DF <- data.frame(score = c(rnorm(n, sd = 10), rnorm(n, sd = 30), rnorm(n, sd = 40)),
                 treatment = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = n),
                 subject = 1:(n*3))

leveneTest(score ~ treatment, DF) # Shows heterogeneity of variance

mdl <- lm(score ~ treatment, data = DF)
emmeans(mdl, ~treatment) # same SE for all the means
# treatment  emmean   SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
# A           0.344 3.99 147    -7.54     8.23
# B           4.392 3.99 147    -3.50    12.28
# C         -10.156 3.99 147   -18.04    -2.27
# Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Is there a way to tweak `lm` (or `lmer`) to take into account unequal variance?

Comment: The following link may be helpful: [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91872/alternatives-to-one-way-anova-for-heteroskedastic-data/91881](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91872/alternatives-to-one-way-anova-for-heteroskedastic-data/91881)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it via `lmer`:

```r
library(lme4)

mdl <- lmer(score ~ treatment + (0 + treatment|subject), data = DF,
              + control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore", 
                                      check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore"))
#Warning messages:
#  1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
#  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
#  2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
#  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues

emmeans(mdl, ~ treatment)
# treatment  emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# A           0.344 1.31 49    -2.29     2.98
# B           4.392 3.84 49    -3.33    12.11
# C         -10.156 5.60 49   -21.40     1.09
# Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
# Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this fits a model for unequal variances. If it does, can you explain?

Answer (score 6):

You can do heterogeneous variance in a variety of ways in R. A simple way is through the `gls` package

```r
library(nlme)
mod = gls(score~treatment, data=DF, 
          weights = varIdent(form = ~1|treatment), 
              method="ML")
emmeans(mod, ~treatment)
```

although `lme4` is more efficient and popular, `nlme` offers a variety of structures for the residuals. Of course you can always go the Bayesian route if you need even more flexibility

```r
library(brms)
modb <- brm(
     bf(score ~ treatment,
        sigma ~ treatment), 
      family = gaussian,
      data=DF)
emmeans(modb, ~ treatment)
```

Comment: Thanks! What about `lmer`, is there an alternative? I am used to that function.

Comment: An alternative is the R package `gamlss`  For an example see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495811/are-there-better-approaches-than-the-weighted-mean/495845#495845

Comment: we can read in an lme4 vignette: “The main advantage of `nlme` relative to `lme4` is a user interface for fitting models with structure in the residuals (various forms of heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation) and in the random-effects covariance matrices (e.g., compound symmetric models).