# Trust the graphs or go with Breusch-Pagan and White's tests for Homoscedasticity on large datasets?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, large-data, breusch-pagan

I have a large dataset (n > 500,000) which I'm building a linear model with `lm(PV1READ ~ PV1MATH + PV1SCIE + ST004D01T)`. Tests for Normality, No multicollinearity, Independence seem fine, but it keeps tripping up on Homoscedasticity. The Breusch-Pagan test `ols_test_breusch_pagan(mdl)` gives:

> Chi2 = 930.8976, Prob > Chi2 = 1.88444e-204

I read elsewhere that B-P tests aren't so good on larger datasets (p values go down the more observations I add), but the White's test gives similar results `white_test_boot(mdl)`:

> Test Statistic: 1053.69, P-value: 0

I would just kick the model out, but the plots look promising, the lines are pretty straight to me:

[image]

But when I plot the *Studentized* Residuals, a large number of points are |Residual| > 2

[image]

> sum(abs(stud_resids)>2)/ length(stud_resids)

Which equates to ~5% overall, which seem ok.

Am I missing something? Can I just use the graphs instead of the tests if the dataset is large enough? And how would I report that?

Comment: I believe that proposed duplicate addresses this. If not, please say what remains unclear, and we can talk through it in the comments, or I can reopen the question to allow for a full answer.

Comment: Like [all Lagrange-multiplier (LM) tests](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Econometric_Methods_with_Applications_in/2TVtDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA239), the Breusch-Pagan test can be written as $n R^2$, where $n$ is your sample size and the $R^2$ is that of the auxiliary regression of the squared residuals of your model on $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_k$. For a large enough $n$, this test will *always* reject. Which is to say: trust your eyes, and your common sense.

Comment: Thanks @Durden, does the same problem exist with whites test?

Comment: [White's test is also an LM test](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/whitestrap/whitestrap.pdf#page=2), so the same logic applies.

Comment: Bottom line: when your sample size is in the hundreds of thousands, these tests will exceed usual "critical values" for the tiniest deviations from pure homoscedasticity; deviations that aren't meaningful enough warrant an [adjustment of your model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/639207).